# How to replace text in specific column?

Tags: linux, shell

Suppose I have a text with the following content, with the file name `test.txt`.

```
anmn    gzcn    anmn
devy    dybu    devy
emli    ixco    emli
udnx    qmse    udnx
lhdh    hcdi    lhdh
```

I need to replace the characters in column 3 with preset content.

The preset content is stored in another file, for example `file1.txt`.

```
msit
ccps
ybwg
kgjs
uxxs
```

It is worth noting that the replacement characters in these two files are not in the same order, and their corresponding replacement relationships are as follows.

```
anmn    ->    ybwg
devy    ->    kgjs
emli    ->    msit
udnx    ->    uxxs
lhdh    ->    ccps
```

The expected output would be:

```
anmn    gzcn    ybwg
devy    dybu    kgjs
emli    ixco    msit
udnx    qmse    uxxs
lhdh    hcdi    ccps
```

Is it possible to do this through a simple shell script?

Comment: Why not? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Check out awk. Set `FS`and `OFS` to proper values and just convert your logic to code: `NR==1{$3="ybwg"}{print}` and so on.

Comment: Where do we get the *"preset content"* from exactly, please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The replacement content needs to be set manually, such as replacing `anmn` with `ybwg`.

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried a Google search before asking the question, but I didn't figure out how I should do this using awk because of errors in the testing process.

Comment: @JamesBrown `cat test.txt | awk -F " " '{if ($3==anmn) $3=ybwg}1'`  This is what I have tried and it did not replace successfully, what is wrong please?

Comment: `awk '{if ($3=="anmn") $3="ybwg"}1' test.txt` Without quotes the non-reserved words are variables.

Comment: Then please share more details by editing your question. This should include answers to all comments if possible

Comment: @NicoHaase Sorry, I will refine it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the replacement values are in a file file1.txt:

```
anmn ybwg
devy kgjs 
emli msit
udnx uxxs
lhdh ccps
```

You can use awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { map[$1]=$2;next } { $3=map[$3]}1' file1.txt text.txt
```

Process the file with the replacements first (FNR==NR) and create an array map with the first space separated field as the index and the second space separated field ($1) as the value. Then when processing the second file, set the third space separated field to the value of the third field index in map and also set the output record separator to be the same as the input record separator. Print all records by specifying 1.

Comment: Thank for your help! This test does work, but it relies on sorting relationships. If the substitution correspondence is defined in the `file1.txt` file, e.g. `anmn` corresponds to `ybwg`, and so on. Then awk replaces the matching characters according to the correspondence, is this possible?

Comment: No worries. I've amended the solution to have the mappings in file1.txt

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly!
PS: The `aawk` in the command needs to be modified. :)